# To pull data from multiple databases into one using SSIS package but want to limit staging table to one

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

In my current requirement, We have one DataMart database in which we pull data from many other databases.

The schema for The table may not be same across all the databases.

**Question 1**: *is it possible to have one common SSIS package to pull data from all the source databases though schema may be different across the databases.*

My understanding is as schema is not same and thus transformation will be different for each database. Hence I am considering separate SSIS package per source database.

SSIS package current design :
**truncate staging table -> pull data from source into staging table + transformation + add source column value** [I need to keep track of datasource as well as a column i.e if source is DB1, DB2..] **-> merge in main table**
with above design (truncate step as first step) I am forced to have one staging table per source database. (i.e if I have total 5 table and total 3 source databases then I need to have 15 staging tables)

**Question 2** : is it possible to manage with one staging table for all source databases (i.e (i.e if I have total 5 table and total 3 source databases; still I can manage with just 5 staging tables/ common staging table for all source databases)

NOTE: SSIS packages may run simultaneously for DB1,DB2..

**My idea** for common staging table is define new column in staging table : "isRecordProcessed". SSIS package design :: **step 1** - delete all records with isRecordProcessed true. **step 2** - pull data from source into staging table + transformation + add source column value. **Step 3** merge in main table **step 4** mark this record as processed i.e isRecordProcessed=true.

**But problem** I see with solution is lets say *while SSIS pkg1 is in execution SSIS pkg2 is also fired. Now as step 1 this will remove all the processed records of SSIS Pkg1. which may invalidate ongoing SSIS pkg1::forloop counter [MERGE step] and it may result in skipping some records as part of MERGE step*

Comment: Please modify the question with your comment. Thanks

Comment: @Hiten004 - done updated

Comment: There are tools designed to combine data from different sources in the dataflow, and maybe some of them would be useful to you, but it is impossible to say based on the little you have told us about your data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1:**

Yes you can do iu with 1 SSIS with three data flows

**Answer 2:**

As long as your schema for all 5 table are in the 1 stagging table. but I would create 5 staging table and load them from 3 databases at same time.

**You can do one big package with all the ETL tasks.**

**But problem**

Run package2 after package 1 is finish.

Hope this help.

Comment: for answer 2, how can I ensure that package 2 is always executed once pkg1 is over?  can I have one single SSIS package for all source DBs to manage DELTA and put sequential container/dataFlowTask for each source per table. i.e. Container1 for table1 wrt sourceDB1, Container2 for table1 wrt sourceDB2, Container3 for table1 wrt sourceDB3 similarly for all tables.

Comment: You can do one big package with all the ETL tasks then using  container/dataFlowTask run them in sequance and/parrelle them .